# selected no funciona en select multiple en angular 4

Tags: angular, angular5

la propiedad selected no funciona en angular 4. por ejemplo si hago un ciclo

```
<select multiple >
<option *ngFor="let opt of model" selected>
   opt.name
</option>
```

y hay 10 option solo va a seleccionar el ultimo elemento. Esto me sucede en cualquier proyecto que haga de angular. Cualquier for que le ponga , y si le pongo selected no selecciona todos como deberia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
<select multiple >
<option *ngFor="let opt of model" [attr.selected]="true">
   opt.name
</option>
```

Aunque lo ideal sería usar un formulario, asociar el select con un valor (un array) que tengas en tu controlador y dejar que Angular seleccionase las opciones que coincidiesen.